# How to resolve error "Run-Time Check Failure #3"?

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on MS Visual Studio. I keep on  getting this error:

"Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'test' is being used without being initialized."

I don't have any idea how to solve this. Here is the code that I'm currently tries to modify:

```
STDMETHODIMP CButtonDemoBHO::Exec(const GUID*, DWORD nCmdID, DWORD d, VARIANTARG*, VARIANTARG* pvaOut)
{

   CRebarHandler *test;

   switch (nCmdID){
   case BUTTON_PRESSED:
      MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"You have pressed the button", L"Button Pressed", MB_OK);
      test->findButton(m_hWnd);
      test->setmenu();
      break;

   case MENU_ITEM_SELECT:
      MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"You have simulated a button press with the menu ", L"Menu Pressed", MB_OK);
      break;

    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CRebarHandler *test;

switch (nCmdID){
  case BUTTON_PRESSED:
   MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"You have pressed the button", L"Button Pressed", MB_OK);
   test->findButton(m_hWnd); // <= using test without initialization
   test->setmenu();
// ...
```

In those last two lines you're using the uninitialized `test` pointer. Since it wasn't initialized, it might point just anywhere in memory, and the chunk it accidentally points to will be interpreted as a `CRebarHandler` object. That's undefined behavior at its best, and could do ***anything***. Be glad it blows up right away.

I don't know what a `CRebarHandler` is, but can't you use one as an automatic object? Something  like:

```
CRebarHandler test( /`...whatever it takes...*/ ); // no pointer

switch (nCmdID){
  case BUTTON_PRESSED:
   MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"You have pressed the button", L"Button Pressed", MB_OK);
   test.findButton(m_hWnd);
   test.setmenu();
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared test, but never assigned anything to it. You have a pointer to nothing. That thing could be NULL or anything. Using it to call a pointer is not safe.

Comment: On a 32bit machine, `NULL` is just one of 2^32 possible values. Depending on what previously used the memory now occupied by `test`, the probability of it being `NULL` might be less than 1/1^32, but it's still very low.

Comment: That's what the "or anything" was for. What is certain is that the probability that it points to a valid object is vanishingly unlikely.